# What is the best way to troubleshoot a while infinite loop in python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, infinite-loop

I'm trying to teach myself python and I am stuck in the for/while loops. Now I know the difference between the two but once nested loops get involved, i'm left feeling all over the place in terms of determining the hierarchy of the loops. Is there a way that I can get better at this? and how do I troubleshoot my loops once it gives me back an infinite loop? :(

for example: this code I was writing, to count the number of specific colored cars on each level of a garage.

```
level=1
red=0
blue=0
black=0
white=0
total=0
done=0
totalperlevel=0
sumofcars=0
currentlevel=0
cars=0
while level < 6:
    cars=input(f"Enter the colour of a car on level {level}:").lower()
    level+=1
    while cars != done:
        if cars == red:
            totalperlevel=totalperlevel+1
            red=red+1
        elif cars == blue:
            blue=blue+1
            totalperlevel=totalperlevel+1
        elif cars == white:
            totalperlevel=totalperlevel+1
            white=whitecar+1
        elif cars == black:
            black=black+1
            totalperlevel=totalperlevel+1
        else:
            totalperlevel=totalperlevel
        sumofcars= red+blue+white+black
        cars=input(f"Enter the colour of a car on level {level}:").lower()
    print(f"Total number of the 4-colours cars on Level {level} is {totalperlevel}")
    
print(f"Total number of red cars in the garage: {red}")
print(f"Total number of blue cars in the garage: {blue}")
print(f"Total number of black cars in the garage: {black}")
print(f"Total number of white cars in the garage: {white}")
print(f"Total number of the 4-colours cars altogether: {sumofcars}")
```

Comment: your second inner while loop makes no sense, `cars` is supposed to be a color but `done` is an `int`. that condition will never be met, same goes for the equality conditions, you are checking a string against an `int`

Comment: All those comparisons should be with strings, e.g. `if cars == 'done':`

Comment: @JoshClark `level` is incremented in `level+=1` right after `cars=input...`

Comment: You should use `for level in range(6):` instead of `while level < 6:`

Comment: You need to set `totalpelevel` back to 0 at the beginning of each level.

Comment: what is `done` supposed to even be? it never gets incremented

Comment: Asking us to teach you debugging in general is not sufficiently focused.
See this [lovely debugging site](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for help.
Also, please make sure that you do appropriate research before posting a question here -- including the SO posting guidelines.

Comment: thank you for the help, I guess I should have nailed that down from the get go, seems that I need to master the basics before proceeding. still learning i'm afraid. But thanks for the fixes, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to troubleshoot any looping is to write down the variables and keep track of them as the code continues. This is called tracing your code. This example should help: [tracing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jq5ac_BNzHs)

As others have pointed out that cars is a string and done is an integer. They will never be the same.

Comment: thank you for the help, I guess I should have nailed that down from the get go. still learning i'm afriad. But thanks for the fix, I appreciate it!

Comment: Of course, glad that I can help. You can only learn by making mistakes. I recommend doing problems on W3resource (https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/), and they provide helpful solutions with countless problems.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of debugging, I highly recommend PyCharm. It has a great debugging experience that will allow you to step through your code line by line.

Other than that, `print` statements are your friend. Use them while developing to see intermediary states. You could also use the python logging module with debug statements.

From your code; A few things to make this easier.

- Use a for loop for the levels. This will make incrementing easier.
- Use a dict to store the color info. This will reduce repetition.
- Use strings instead of numbers to make this inputs clearer.
- Calculate the total number after getting all the colors. If some data can be inferred from another, this usually makes the loop less busy overall.

```
num_levels = 6
all_colors = ["red", "white", "blue", "black"]
level_count = {level: 0 for level in range(num_levels)}
color_count = {color: 0 for color in all_colors}

for level in range(num_levels):
    prompt = f"Enter the color of a car on level {level}: "
    while True:
        color = input(prompt).lower()
        if color == "done":
            break  # This exits the while loop
        elif color in all_colors:
            level_count[level] += 1
            color_count[color] += 1
        else:
            print("Invalid color, try again.")

for level, count in level_count.items():
    print(f"Total number of the 4-colours cars on Level {level} is {count}")

for color, count in color_count.items():
    print(f"Total number of {color} cars in the garage: {count}")

total_count = sum(color_count.values())
print(f"Total number of the 4-colours cars altogether: {total_count}")
```

Comment: Oh my, i'm so thankful for this. I think I still need to learn/master the basics considering I am way over my head. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ElDaniel Everyone is always learning (and if they're not they should be)! Sometimes you gotta jump in the deep end to figure things out! Good luck!